# Placemark с button yandex

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такое:
Открываешь Placemark в нем кнопка выбрать, после ее нажатия на странице нужно перезаписать значение поля.

```
...
balloonContentFooter: '<button type="button" class="selectSalon" data-name="Название блауна" data-coord="59.324х23.323423">Выбрать</button>'
...
```

Слушать нажатие через jQuery явно не получится:

```
$('.selectSalon').on('click', function(){
    console.log('enter');
    console.log(this.data('name'));
});
```

Да и стили кнопке не поставишь.

Как быть?

Comment: В этом вопросе обсуждали, как работать с jQuery в балунах https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772234/Узнать-ширину-div-с-widthauto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.650625, 37.62708],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        counter = 0,

        // Создание макета содержимого балуна.
        // Макет создается с помощью фабрики макетов с помощью текстового шаблона.
        BalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            '<div style="margin: 10px;">' +
                '<b>{{properties.name}}</b><br />' +
                '<i id="count"></i> ' +
                '<button id="counter-button"> +1 </button>' +
            '</div>', {

            // Переопределяем функцию build, чтобы при создании макета начинать
            // слушать событие click на кнопке-счетчике.
            build: function () {
                // Сначала вызываем метод build родительского класса.
                BalloonContentLayout.superclass.build.call(this);
                // А затем выполняем дополнительные действия.
                $('#counter-button').bind('click', this.onCounterClick);
                $('#count').html(counter);
            },

            // Аналогично переопределяем функцию clear, чтобы снять
            // прослушивание клика при удалении макета с карты.
            clear: function () {
                // Выполняем действия в обратном порядке - сначала снимаем слушателя,
                // а потом вызываем метод clear родительского класса.
                $('#counter-button').unbind('click', this.onCounterClick);
                BalloonContentLayout.superclass.clear.call(this);
            },

            onCounterClick: function () {
                $('#count').html(++counter);
                if (counter == 5) {
                    alert('Вы славно потрудились.');
                    counter = 0;
                    $('#count').html(counter);
                }
            }
        });

    var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.650625, 37.62708], {
            name: 'Считаем'
        }, {
            balloonContentLayout: BalloonContentLayout,
            // Запретим замену обычного балуна на балун-панель.
            // Если не указывать эту опцию, на картах маленького размера откроется балун-панель.
            balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0
        });

    map.geoObjects.add(placemark);
}
```